# Database change with software update

Tags: python, sqlite

I've got a program which has a database with a certain schema, `v0.1.0`.

In my next version (`v0.1.1`) I've made changes to the database schema.

So when I update to (`0.1.1`) I would like those changes to take effect without effecting the original data in (`0.1.0`) and subsequent versions.

How do I go about making the changes without affecting (`0.1.0`) database data and keeping track of those changes in subsequent versions?

I'm using python with `sqlite3`.

**Update**

There is no support for multiple versions of the software. The database is dependent on the verion that you are using.

The is no concurrent access to the database, 1 database per version.

So the user can use the old version but when they upgrade to the new version the .sqlite schema will be changed.

Comment: Are you using an ORM or any other database abstraction?

Comment: Side note: use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) and make database schema changes that are not backwards compatible a major version change.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of your software reading the same database concurrently? Or do you just want to support downgrading? E.g. you have one database file and version 1 of your software needs to be able to continue to access the data even though version 2 uses a newer schema *in the same file*?

Comment: If you've constructed your schema by hand, you will have to write the migration script by hand. Ideally this is just CREATE-ing new tables/views/indices/keys, ALTER-ing tables to add new columns with default values, and replacing views; otherwise you may also need to dump all the data out and back in (through temporary tables, another db, some other persistence format, etc.).

Comment: And of course you will need to maintain update scripts for every active version of your schema, so you can update 0.1.0 to 0.1.3 (whether in 1 step or 3).

Comment: I'm not using any ORM or datbase abstraction.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there will only be one version the user uses, so when they upgrade the databse will need to be modified accordingly.

Comment: @abarnert Can you please provide an example of a migration script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, I will only mention one.

It seems like you already track the version within the database. On your application start, you will want to check this version against the running application's version and run any sql scripts that will perform the schema changes.

**update**

An example of this in action:

```
import os
import sqlite3 as sqlite

def make_movie_table(cursor):
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE movies(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(20), link VARCHAR(20))')

def make_series_table(cursor):
     cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE series(title VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,series_link VARCHAR(60),number_of_episodes INTEGER,number_of_seasons INTEGER)')

def make_episode_table(cursor):
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE episodes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title VARCHAR(30),episode_name VARCHAR(15), episode_link VARCHAR(40), Date TIMESTAMP, FOREIGN KEY (title) REFERENCES series(title) ON DELETE CASCADE)')

def make_version_table(cursor):
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE schema_versions(version VARCHAR(6))')
    cursor.execute('insert into schema_versions(version) values ("0.1.0")')

def create_database(sqlite_file):
    if not os.path.exists(sqlite_file):
        connection = sqlite.connect(sqlite_file)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
        make_movie_table(cursor)
        make_series_table(cursor)
        make_episode_table(cursor)
        make_version_table(cursor)
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

def upgrade_database(sqlite_file):
    if os.path.exists(sqlite_file):
        connection = sqlite.connect(sqlite_file)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("select max(version) from schema_versions")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        database_version = row[0]
        print('current version is %s' % database_version)

        if database_version == '0.1.0':
            print('upgrading version to 0.1.1')
            cursor.execute('alter table series ADD COLUMN new_column1 VARCHAR(10)')
            cursor.execute('alter table series ADD COLUMN new_column2 INTEGER')
            cursor.execute('insert into schema_versions(version) values ("0.1.1")')

        #if database_version == '0.1.1':
            #print('upgrading version to 0.1.2')
            #etc cetera

        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

#I need to add 2 columns to the series table, when the user upgrade the software.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_database('/tmp/db.sqlite')
    upgrade_database('/tmp/db.sqlite')
```

Each upgrade script will take care of [making your database changes](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), and then update the version inside the DB to the latest version. Note that we do not use `elif` statements, this is so that you can upgrade a database over multiple versions if it needs to.

There are some caveats to watch out for:

- run upgrades [inside transactions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions), you will want to rollback on any errors to avoid leaving the database in an unusable state. -- **update** this is incorrect as pointed out, thanks Martijn!
- avoid renames and column deletes if you can, and if you must, ensure any views using them are updated too.

Comment: Note that `sqlite3` bindings [don't handle DDL in transactions correctly](http://bugs.python.org/issue10740).

Comment: Thanks invert this seems to be what I was looking for. My database changes are all ALTERS.

Answer (score 5):

Track the schema version in the database with the [`user_version` PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version), and keep a sequence of upgrade steps:

```
def get_schema_version(conn):
    cursor = conn.execute('PRAGMA user_version')
    return cursor.fetchone()[0]

def set_schema_version(conn, version):
    conn.execute('PRAGMA user_version={:d}'.format(version))

def initial_schema(conn):
    # install initial schema
    # ...

def ugrade_1_2(conn):
    # modify schema, alter data, etc.

# map target schema version to upgrade step from previous version
upgrade_steps = {
    1: initial_schema,
    2: ugrade_1_2,
}

def check_upgrade(conn):
    current = get_schema_version(conn)
    target = max(upgrade_steps)
    for step in range(current + 1, target + 1):
        if step in upgrade_steps:
            upgrade_steps[step](conn)
            set_schema_version(conn, step)
```

Answer (score -2):

Long term you're going to be better off using an ORM such as [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) with a migration tool like [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: I think the OP has multiple clients reading from the same database file; Alembic will not solve the problem of having multiple versions read a file with a changed schema.

Comment: So you've posted a link only answer ([prone to link rot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)) and not even answered the question at hand. Great resources, but what about the OP's problem?

Comment: @lix; I generally agree about link rot but I suggested techniques (ORMs and migration tools) and provided links to examples. I was making it clear to the OP that there are generally accepted techniques addressing their problem. My post would still be of value with broken links and I did not simply defer the answer.

Comment: @and - I can see that but still, take the links out of your answer and all you have listed is 2 names without any references or examples. Sure it's useful information, but still not necessarily an answer. I feel that this should have been a great comment but still not really an answer.